# Debug a standalone Blazor WebAssembly app in VSCode with **watch**

Tags: visual-studio-code, blazor-webassembly

I want to debug standalone Blazor WebAssembly applicaton with **watch** options in VSCode.

I followed [Debug ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?tabs=visual-studio-code&view=aspnetcore-5.0#vscode) and it works well with breakpoint. However code change does not apply while debugging. But, Run `dotnet wtach run --project /Path/To/Project.csproj` in Terminal does apply code change. So I suspect `launch.json` file should be changed to apply **watch** option.

What should I change to achieve it?

Here is my launch.json, which is auto-generated.

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Ledger.Client.Web",
            "type": "blazorwasm",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Client/Web",
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/439541/debug-a-standalone-blazor-webassembly-app-in-vscod.html),

> You will need VS2019 16.11.2 with Net6 preview 5 or VS2020 preview 1, which has the Net6 preview 5.
> Hot reload didn't work in Net6 preview 4 or Net5.

Comment: .NET 6 is released in production, and still the same issue for debugging through VS Code..

Comment: @HrvojeKusulja I recommand to use command line until this issue resolved.

Comment: I am using Windows, VSCode, ASP.NET 6 Blazor WASM project, and dotnet watch command. However, the breakpoint does not trigger in VSCode on the default template (dotnet new blazorwasm)